# What is ねぇたぁ in 判らねぇたぁ?

Tags: colloquial-language

```
俺は手加減してたぜ？
それが判らねぇたぁ、
お前、割とぬるいねぇ。
```

Is it colloquial form of 判らなかった?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32933/9831  (for とは→たあ), https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29099/9831 (for ない→ねえ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> それが判らねぇたぁ

This is a colloquial form of それが判らないとは.